# Are there any consequences to having negative values in your time series training dataset?

Tags: time-series

I haven't read anything that says you shouldn't have negative values in your time series training dataset, so I was wondering if there are any consequences for having negative values in my training dataset?

Comment: So long as you do not try something strange like taking logarithms, why would it be an issue?

Comment: If you don't like negative values, add a large positive constant to all the numbers in your dataset and proceed from there.  That obviously doesn't lose information.

Comment: Note that negative values don't rule out other transformations, such as cube root, sign(y) log(1 + |y|)) or asinh(y), but none is as near white magic as logarithms can be for essentially multiplicative time series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many time series models assume Gaussian error terms, meaning that all real numbers are possibilities. In that sense, negative values are fine. Those negative values might indicate undesirable outcomes (e.g., losses instead of profits), but you might be modeling something that sometimes has such events (e.g., stock returns).

If you’re in a framework that assumes positive values (modeling counts or distances, for instance), then you have a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I was using a framework that assumes positive values, then what would that problem be?

Comment: It would indicate a problem with your data. If I’m predicting the heights of trees and have a tree height in my data of $-2$ meters, something went wrong with the measurement or entry of that value. OR your assumption about positive values only is wrong. Perhaps negative values are rare but not impossible.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no problem with that. It's just numbers. There's absolutely no meaning to a shift by a constant.

Comment: I think that's too strong a statement. If a variable has a true zero, then adding a constant may destroy meaning. Inflation rate + constant is one such.

Comment: As the question was about a training set, it absolutely does not matter what's the physical meaning of the feature. You would get the exactly same predictions from your model if you shift your feature to be $inflation -100$. Meaning is for humans. Even for temperatures, which have an absolute zero, you can switch from kelvin to ferenheit and get the exact same results with negative numbers.

Comment: Meaning is for anything statistical too.  I think @Dave’s answer and comment are more on target here.